# Receiving error in an attempt to define my table

Tags: mysql, database

I'm working on a group project and I'm trying to drop my database, but I'm receiving the same error, no matter how I try to manipulate what I wrote. Hopefully someone can help me understand where I went wrong.

For the

```
type VARCHAR NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR, 
image VARCHAR,
```

I've tried adding in "DEFAULT NULL" and adding in numbers next to VARCHAR. I keep getting the same error message. I left it as what I put above because with my API, I don't want to restrict the amount of characters I'll be receiving when I call on it.

```
CREATE DATABASE recycleThis_db;
USE recycleThis_db;

CREATE TABLE materials (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    type VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        description VARCHAR, 
        image VARCHAR, 
    materialID INT(11) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I keep getting this error message:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR, 
    image VARCHAR, 
    materialID INT NOT NULL' at line 3

Comment: Google *MySQL reserved words*, and see if you can use `type` as a column name without jumping through hoops. And just for clarity, you're not trying to **DROP** your database. Dropping a database means deleting it, and you're not trying to do so. You're attempting to create a table.

Comment: `type` is a keyword in MySQL, but it's not a Reserved Word   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-T

Answer (score 0):

I believe VARCHAR requires a length specifier e.g. `VARCHAR(10)` or `VARCHAR(250)`

```
CREATE TABLE `materials`
( `id`            INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, `type`          VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
, `description`   VARCHAR(255)
, ...
```

---

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html

excerpt:

> The `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` types are declared *with a length* that indicates the maximum number of characters you want to store. For example, `CHAR(30)` can hold up to 30 characters.